# iptables: Reroute incoming TCP traffic on port to IP inside VPN network

Tags: networking, iptables, network-interface, routing, vpn

I have a remote server with an open port. This server is connected to a VPN network. My local computer is also connected to this VPN network. So, the two computers can communicate.

What I'd like to do is: I'd like to host an http (websocket) server on my local machine and have it available from the Internet by accessing my server's IP address.

I've tried these `iptables` commands, but they do not seem to have worked:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $SERVER_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $LOCAL_MACHINE_VPN_ADDRESS:$SERVER_PORT
```

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d $LOCAL_MACHINE_VPN_ADDRESS --dport $SERVER_PORT -j SNAT --to-source $SERVER_LOCAL_NETWORK_ADDRESS
```

Where the exact values in my case are:

```
SERVER_PORT=6767
LOCAL_MACHINE_VPN_ADDRESS=10.0.1.255
SERVER_LOCAL_NETWORK_ADDRESS=193.108.113.52
```

The `SERVER_LOCAL_NETWORK_ADDRESS` I read from `ip addr` command under `eth0` interface. It had this string: `inet 193.108.113.52/24 scope global eth0`.

I'm kind of lost here. Do I maybe need to explicitly set `eth0` and `wg0` interfaces somehow?

One thing I'm sure about is my VPN configuration: I have `nginx` running on this server, proxying to my local machine, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `SERVER_LOCAL_NETWORK_ADDRESS` I read from `ip addr` command under
> eth0 interface. It had this string: `inet 193.108.113.52/24 scope global eth0`.

As you intend the packet to be routed within the VPN, and there are no special routing adjustments made on LOCAL_MACHINE to allow receiving a public IP address from elsewhere than the usual Internet access (eg: home router), nor special adjustments made to the WireGuard settings to allow this, the POSTROUTING *iptables* command on SERVER should set the address to its local WireGuard tunnel address, not to its public address: above information is not needed and can't work.

Instead, just use `-j MASQUERADE` (because I don't know the remote server's WireGuard address, possibly something like 10.0.1.1, else I could also suggest to change the `-j SNAT` address). So the last `iptables` command below:

> ```
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d $LOCAL_MACHINE_VPN_ADDRESS --dport $SERVER_PORT -j SNAT --to-source $SERVER_LOCAL_NETWORK_ADDRESS
> ```

should be replaced with:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d $LOCAL_MACHINE_VPN_ADDRESS --dport $SERVER_PORT -j MASQUERADE
```

---

Notes:

In all cases, performing SNAT or MASQUERADE will prevent the websocket service to see the actual IP address of the Internet client: the address will always be the one on the remote server.

To have the websocket service see the actual public address of the Internet client requires actual *routing*, involving [policy-based routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) because LOCAL_MACHINE has now to be multi-homed, rather than using NAT. This require knowing the full network configuration of both remote server and local server, including its WireGuard configuration, which were not provided, to know what to change.

As a reminder, *iptables* (or *nftables* or *Netfilter*) doesn't route. It can alter addresses or other properties that can be related to routing, and if this alteration is done before the routing stack sees them (eg: PREROUTING), then this can indirectly alter the routing decision. Actual routing is done using `ip route`, and for policy-based routing, also using `ip rule`, or using network configuration tools doing the same as these commands.

Comment: Sorry, I tried your configuration, but it seems to not work in my case:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6767 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.255:6767
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.1.255 --dport 6767 -j MASQUERADE
```

Am I getting something wrong? 

My Wireguard "host" machine is `10.0.0.1/24` and my local PC is `10.0.1.255/24` - it's where I'm trying to reach from the internet via the server.

UFW rules:

VPN "host":
```
sudo ufw allow 6767/tcp
```

Local PC:

```
sudo ufw allow in on wg0 to any port 6767 proto tcp
```

Comment: That's already an issue: if 10.0.0.1/24 and 10.0.1.255/24 are not in the same "LAN" that probably means the WireGuard's AllowedIPs don't match for communication. But you wrote "So, the two computers can communicate." . Maybe they can't but you think they can because they can through a 3rd party server in the VPN network. I'll probably delete this answer because I realize without *all* the information it's just guessing.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm not very proficient at networking. Your answer helps, though.

Comment: Can't delete it now it's accepted. You'll have to run tcpdump everywhere to check what happens. I think this most likely now involves the WireGuard configuration in the 3 places. If you don't own the "VPN network", this might become difficult to change adequate WG configurations. It depends on every details.

Comment: And I also missed it in the comment there's UFW in use: additional iptables rules. You should remove any firewall while testing, but at the same time this exposes the public server...

Comment: Last but not least: run as root `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` : the remote server has to be routing.